# How to create a Row from a List or Array in Spark using java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

In Java, I use RowFactory.create() to create a Row:

```
Row row = RowFactory.create(record.getLong(1), record.getInt(2), record.getString(3));
```

where "record" is a record from a database, but I cannot know the length of "record" in advance, so I want to use a List or an Array to create the "row". In Scala, I can use Row.fromSeq() to create a Row from a List or an Array, but how can I achieve that in Java?

Answer (score 17):

We often need to create Datasets or Dataframes in real world applications. Here is an example of how to create Rows and Dataset in a Java application:

```
// initialize first SQLContext
SQLContext sqlContext = ... 
StructType schemata = DataTypes.createStructType(
        new StructField[]{
                createStructField("NAME", StringType, false),
                createStructField("STRING_VALUE", StringType, false),
                createStructField("NUM_VALUE", IntegerType, false),
        });
Row r1 = RowFactory.create("name1", "value1", 1);
Row r2 = RowFactory.create("name2", "value2", 2);
List<Row> rowList = ImmutableList.of(r1, r2);
Dataset<Row> data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowList, schemata);
```

```
+-----+------------+---------+
| NAME|STRING_VALUE|NUM_VALUE|
+-----+------------+---------+
|name1|      value1|        1|
|name2|      value2|        2|
+-----+------------+---------+
```

Comment: @thank you , in scala we will do sc.paralallize(List((x,y),(a,b))).toDF("col1","col2"), it is so simple , why these Row , JavaRDD and etc ? any simple way like that ?

Comment: You are saying you need to create Dataset in real world applications and making a hard definition of the all variables. Does not make any sense. In the real world everything has to be parameterizable and beforehand  you do not know the values.

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure if I get your question correctly but you can use the RowFactory to create Row from ArrayList in java.

```
List<MyData> mlist = new ArrayList<MyData>();
    mlist.add(d1);
    mlist.add(d2);

Row row = RowFactory.create(mlist.toArray());
```

Comment: hi, when I use your method,  I found spark regard mlist as a whole object:

`Row row = RowFactory.create(mlist);`

`System.out.println("row number:" + row.length());`

`System.out.println("mlist number:" + mlist.size());`

I got:
row number:1
mlist number:2

Comment: Yes but Row will have both records.You can try printing System.out.println("row number:" + row.toSeq());

Comment: hi, thanks so much!
And you can try this:
Object[] rowArray = {obj1, obj2, ....}
Row row = RowFactory.create(rowArray);
System.out.println("row number:" + row.length());
You will get - row number:6

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer. I checked the source code for RowFactory and GenericRow class.-"An internal row implementation that uses an array of objects as the underlying storage."

Answer (score 0):

//Create a a list of DTO

```
List<MyDTO> dtoList = Arrays.asList(.....));
```

//Create a Dataset of DTO

```
Dataset<MyDTO> dtoSet = sparkSession.createDataset(dtoList,
                Encoders.bean(MyDTO.class));
```

//If you need dataset of Row

```
Dataset<Row> rowSet= dtoSet .select("col1","col2","col3");
```

Answer (score -1):

For simple list values you can use `Encoders`:

```
 List<Row> rows = ImmutableList.of(RowFactory.create(new Timestamp(currentTime)));
 Dataset<Row> input = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rows, Encoders.TIMESTAMP().schema());
```